# Expression Engine 404 issues

Tags: templates, http-status-code-404, expressionengine

I'm having an issue getting a good system of setting up 404s that are manageable in the particular way I like to do things in Expression Engine. I'm using the in-built 404 option and it seems to work perfectly except for one thing.

For all my general pages like about us, terms, etc I like to have a URL along the lines of:

domain.com/index.php/about-us

I simply tell my default template in my home group to pull in a post name from a certain channel which works fine, but this triggers 404s when they're switch on in the system.

I thought this might be because the channel with this in was named differently to the home group but renaming them to match gave me internal server errors. Also I find it odd that with no 404 page selected I still get basic 404 pages around the place but not for these general pages.

What I need to know is there anyway to get it to recognise the top level links as valid without having to either make a template entry for each of them or create my own 404 system with redirects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely happening because you have Strict 404s enabled in your Global Template Preferences.

My suggestion though is to simply create these pages using the Pages module, which is the more standardized way to create non-template-based URLs in EE.

Comment: Thanks Derek, I'd completely forgotten about the Pages module. I've used it before but it's not become habit yet, time to change that.